# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy probando por primera vez la librería FPDF para generar archivos PDF. Descargué la versión 18.2, y expandí el zip en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra mi proyecto. Estoy trabajando en XAMPP.

Lo primero que hice fue lo básico, ejecuté el tuto1.php ahí mismo donde se encuentra, y funcionó bien, así que supuse que todo estaba bien encaminado. Así luce mi directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego me copié el mismo código del tuto1.php a mi archivo generateInvoice.php, le modifiqué la ruta porque mi archivo está en el directorio invoice y cuando trato de ejecutarlo, falla. El error  es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already
> been output, can't send PDF file in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\fpdf\fpdf.php(1060): FPDF->Error('Some data
> has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\fpdf\fpdf.php(999):
> FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\ProjMant.php(111):
> FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

el código en generateInvoice.php es:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene el archivo `generateInvoice.php`?

Comment: ese archivo tiene el código que puse al final, voy a ponerle el nombre del archivo para que sea más claro

Comment: Pero contiene ¿únicamente eso?; pareciera que en algún lado (no dentro de la librería) hay un `echo`

Comment: no, eso es todo, yo tambien pensé en lo que dices porque ví una rspuesta en otro lado que era eso, pero no hay ningún echo

Comment: ¿Y en qué momento entra `ProjMant.php`? Considera que cuando digo `echo` también me refiero a cualquier método que genera salida, incluyendo  `print`, `print_r`, etc. y cualquier caracter fuera de las etiquetas de php.

Comment: en ProjMant se encuentra un botón que llama a generaInvoice. Finalmente pude arreglarlo, pero lo que hice fue llamar a generaInvoice desde una función JavaScript, y así si ha funcionado, supongo que hay demasiadas cosas en ProjMant

Comment: A mi me paso lo mismo, eliminando los echo, a vuelto a funcionar

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que se está enviando algo a la salida antes del PDF. Es probable que lo puedas arreglar de la siguiente forma:

Verifica que antes del tag **`<?php`** o después no hayan espacios. Si usas Sublime Text hay plugins para verificar eso.

Si no, prueba el siguiente código:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: Hola, @ABlack Por favor retroalimenta de manera más detallada el código que proporcionaste, de forma en que no solo la persona que hizo esta pregunta sepa por qué debe de utilizar tu código, sino también otras personas que tengan un problema similar al de esta pregunta. Si tienes más dudas, por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) donde encontrarás más detalles de lo que te comenté anteriormente. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias!, no se me había ocurrido usar el flush para eso. Ahora ya no da ese error, aunque tampoco me está abriendo el archivo, me da un mensaje de error al tratar de abrirlo. Voy a ver si logro resolver eso yo.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, gracias a la orientación recibida, pude resolverlo. Lo que hice fue llamar a generateInvoice.php desde una función en JavaScript en lugar de incluirlo en el ProjMan.

Creo que el problema es que en ProjMan existían varios echo, yo pensé que no afectarían al estar en otras partes de código, pero de alguna manera parece que se cuelan.

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que tu archivo nuevo esta en al carpeta invoice, por lo cual debes hacer referencia a script fpdf.php junto con su ruta, debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

Comment: si, disculpa, tienes razón, es que después estuve probando otras cosas y cuando puse la consulta copié directamente del archivo tuto1.php en lugar de mi archivo, por si acaso lo corregí y volví a probarlo y sigue dando el error